# How can I clear the cache in an Outlook client programmatically?

Tags: caching, vbscript, outlook-2003, outlook-form

I am executing the following routine often in order to clear the local cache of many Outlook clients (Outlook 2003) in order to fix corrupted Forms stored on the users local drive.

1. On the Tools menu, click Options, and then click the Other tab.
2. Click Advanced Options.
3. In the Advanced Options box, click Custom Forms.
4. In the Custom Forms box, click Manage Forms.
5. In the Forms Manager box, click Clear Cache.

Is there a way I can ***program*** this to occur on the local client?

I am looking for a solution that could be included in Outlooks VBScript in order to include it in yet another 'Organizational Forms Library' Forms client side validation code.